# unity 3d error how to fix it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am starting my project and i got this error can't figure out what's wrong with it.
Really appreaciate help and sorry if it's stupid question. I am still new at unity. Thanks for all the answers.

I tried searching for help about this vector2(width,height) but to me it looks all fine.
And also if anyone can please explain to my about this rect.center problem why did i got it?

Unity3d Error:

```
Assets/Scenes/Game/Scripts/GUI/GameGUI.cs(22,22): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Rect' does not contain a definition for `center' and no extension method `center' of type `UnityEngine.Rect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameGUI : MonoBehaviour {


    void OnResume() {
        enabled = true;
    }

    void OnPause() {
        enabled = false;
    }


    void OnGUI() {
        int fps = (int) (1f/Time.deltaTime*Time.timeScale);
        GUILayout.Box( "FPS "+fps );

        Vector2 size = GUI.skin.label.CalcSize( new GUIContent("+") );
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
        rect.center = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height)/2f;
        GUI.Label( rect, "+" );
    }


}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The problem is not with Vector2. The error says that the Rect class doesn't have a variable called center. However, it does have that (http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rect-center.html).

Maybe, as the error message say, you are missing a reference? Also have you tried right-clicking on the Rect class's name and then choosing "Go to definition", to see if that variable is present in the class? Maybe you're using an old version of Unity, tried checking that?

Comment: I created a test class GameGUI under Unity 3.5.6 and it compiles without errors. Must be some setting. Strange

Comment: Hmm, mine version is 3.2 i think. I am using UniScite so i don't have such function as to "Go to definition".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `center` property was introduced in Unity 3.5 according to [Unity's Script Reference History page.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/40_history.html#3.5.0). So you have to calculate the center on your own. Maybe your constructor should look something like this:

```
Rect rect = new Rect(Screen.width/2f, Screen.height/2f, size.x, size.y);
```

Comment: "The center property was introduced in Unity 3.5 according to" Yeah i think that's the case, thanks for your answer. I tried your way with:
`codeRect rect = new Rect(Screen.width/2f, Screen.width/2f, size.x, size.y);` It dosen't worked.

Comment: Oops, the 2nd parameter must be `Screen.height/2f` instead of `Screen.width/2f`. I updated my answer.

Comment: +1 Nice catch.  I wish the Unity script reference had a revision drop down.